# Single ObservableCollection for multiple DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am attempting to upload a list of files to a database.  The way the load works is that a user selects a file, and then that file is read into an ObservableCollection.  The data consists of FileMeta information and Fund Information.  For each file, if some fund information is missing, then the fund is displayed to the user to fill in the missing information.  It is possible that multiple files can contain the same fund with missing information.  I am displaying missing fund information on a file by file basis.  My goal is to have one Fund model and multiple displays of fund information.  When the fund information is updated in one location, I want that update reflected in all locations.  I've been able to display the fund information in multiple places, but not with the one model in the background.  How can I get one model behind all of my datagrids?

[image: User Interface]

### xaml

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedUploadFile}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Removed for brevity-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                    
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Funds}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="200">                            
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fund Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=FundName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                            
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
   </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

### ViewModel

```
public class AuditTests : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Objects
    FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader();

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileMeta> Files { get; set; }

    public AuditTests()
    {
        // Collection Initialization
        InitializeData();
    }

    public void InitializeData()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileMeta>() { new FileMeta () };
    }

    private void AddFileRequested()
    {
        Files = new ObservableCollection<FileMeta>() { new FileMeta () };
        SaveFilesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

### FileMeta

```
public partial class FileMeta : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Fund> _funds;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public FileMeta()
    {
        Funds = new ObservableCollection<Fund>();
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Fund> Funds
    {
        get
        {
            return _funds;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_funds != value)
            {
                _funds = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Funds");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### FileLoader

```
public class FileLoader
{
    public ObservableCollection<Fund> Funds { get; set; }

    public void LoadFile(FileMeta file)
    {
        newFund = GetFund(row.Cell(1).Value.ToString());
        file.Funds.Add(newFund);
    }

    private Fund GetFund(string fundName)
        {
            using (var db = new IISContext())
            {
                // If it exists in the database
                if ((from f in db.Fund where f.FundName == fundName select f).Count() == 0)
                {
                    // If we've already loaded this time
                    var existingFunds = (from f in Funds where f.FundName == fundName select f);
                    if (existingFunds.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        Fund newFund = new Fund();
                        newFund.FundId = Guid.NewGuid();
                        newFund.Cusip = "";
                        newFund.FundFamilyId = (from ff in db.FundFamily where ff.FundFamilyName == "Default" select ff.FundFamilyId).First();
                        newFund.FundName = fundName;
                        Funds.Add(newFund);
                        return newFund;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return existingFunds.First();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return (from f in db.Fund where f.FundName == fundName select f).First();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

### Fund

```
public partial class Fund : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private Guid _fundID;
        private string _cusip;
        private string _fundName;
        private bool _selected;
        private FundFamily _fundFamily;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public Fund()
        {
            PortfolioHolding = new HashSet<PortfolioHolding>();
        }

        public Guid FundId
        {
            get
            {
                return _fundID;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fundID != value)
                {
                    _fundID = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FundID");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Cusip
        {
            get
            {
                return _cusip;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_cusip != value)
                {
                    _cusip = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Cusip");
                }
            }
        }

        public Guid FundFamilyId { get; set; }

        public string FundName
        {
            get
            {
                return _fundName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fundName != value)
                {
                    _fundName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FundName");
                }
            }
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool Selected
        {
            get
            {
                return _selected;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selected != value)
                {
                    _selected = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Selected");
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual ICollection<PortfolioHolding> PortfolioHolding { get; set; }

        public virtual FundFamily FundFamily
        {
            get
            {
                return _fundFamily;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_fundFamily != value)
                {
                    _fundFamily = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("FundFamily");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a master list of Funds. Each time you load a Fund from a file, check the master list first for that Fund (assuming they've got a unique ID of some kind; ticker symbol maybe?). If it's already there, use the existing instance instead of creating a new one. If it's not already there, create it and add it to the master list.

Either that, or every time you update a Fund, recursively search your collection of Files for Funds with the same identity as the one you just updated, and update them to match.

What you want is like this:

```
AuditTests
    Files: [
        FileMeta
            Funds: [ Fund A, Fund C ]

        FileMeta 
            Funds: [ Fund A, Fund B, Fund D ]
    ]

FileLoader
    Funds: [ Fund A, Fund B, Fund C, Fund D ]
```

Where "Fund A", doesn't just mean they look the same, it's the same actual `Fund` object instance.

And `Fund` needs to properly implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I am already doing this for the initial load of the fund list.  Once the load is complete, I want users to be able to select a file and see a `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` of all funds associated with that file. The difficulty I'm having is with 1. Displaying the correct funds for each file 2. Persisting any changes made in one `RowDetailsTemplate` across all `RowDetailsTemplate`'s

Comment: @TimHutchison Please share XAML for the whole Grid in your question, so I can understand better. Does `FileMeta` represent a single file with multiple Funds? If the same actual `Fund` instances are in two collections, and if `Fund` properly implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, 2 should happen automatically.

Comment: @TimHutchison `Funds = fileLoader.Funds` -- does that mean you're using the same *collection* for all of them? Then of course they'll all show the same collection of Funds. That's notwhat I meant at all.

Comment: My thought was that I would filter each display based on which funds came from which file, but that may not be the best way to go...Haven't quite been able to wrap my head around it.  FileMeta is one file and can have multiple Funds.  Question update to follow...

Comment: @TimHutchison Your XAML looks fine to me at first glance. Filtering the collection for each Details isn't the way XAML wants to do things, though I'm quite sure it's possible. The path of least resistance -- which with XAML is pretty much always best in the long run -- is for each `FileMeta` to have its own `Funds` collection that contains its own subset of the `Fund` objects in the master collection.

Comment: I get what you're saying...I wasn't quite putting it all together in my head previously.  I've modified my code, but I'm still missing something.  Could you take a second look?  I'm wondering if I'm not referencing the same fund, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Does Fund implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes it does - I have added the Fund class to the question

Comment: So what exactly are you seeing, and what did you expect to see instead?

Comment: When I add two files that have the same Fund in them and I update the Fund CUSIP on the one Fund, I would expect to see the Fund CUSIP on the other File change to match.  However, when I look at the other Fund, none of the Fund information has changed.

Comment: The only thing I'm seeing is `FundId` raises PropertyChanged with `"FundID", capital "D". I might try putting `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()` calls in `GetFund()` to make sure it's doing what it looks like it's doing. Or give `Fund` a static counter int and a public instance int UniqueID property. In the constructor, `UniqueID = _staticNextUniqueID++;` -- and add a column for it temporarily. Then you tell if they're the same object.